# How can I kill a process by name in Rust

Tags: rust

```rs
    #[cfg(windows)]
    {
    std::process::Command::new("taskkill").args(&["/IM", name, "/F"]).output().ok();
    }
    #[cfg(unix)]
    {
        std::process::Command::new("pkill").arg(name).output().ok();
    }
```

I could do this but I don't like it

Comment: "I could do this but I don't like it" why? What about the solution you already have is insufficient?

Comment: @JaredSmith, ...I'm not the OP, but _I_ don't like it because depending on external executables means you're adding dependencies for things that one could, in theory, do completely in-process (on a UNIXy system, by scanning procfs and sending TERM signals directly). Sure, `pkill` is a _common_ tool, but if you're on an embedded system that ships with only the executables that are directly part of the program you're running, keeping that set (of mandatory executables) small has value.

Comment: even on different flavors of unix, process management (`ps`, `pgrep`...) is system dependent. You could reimplement it yourself (parsing `/proc/` on Linux for example) but since it's already done in `pkill`, is it worth the effort?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's a good guess and I wouldn't balk at not wanting to shell out for that... although the fact the OP is using `std` increases the odds that it's not necessarily an embedded application. Still this is all speculation, and we could easily answer based on wrong assumptions, which is why I asked ... :P

Comment: Using the shell in my experience has many times lead to bad and fragile code, I like to avoid it if I can.

Comment: @OriónGonzález, while I agree with you that doing things in-process is typically more robust, your existing code doesn't use a shell at all. If you ran `Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg("pkill name")`, _that_ would be using a shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK `std` doesn't support querying process info.

Looks like https://crates.io/crates/sysinfo does what you need provided you're okay with the bloat that comes with all the included features.

You'll have to iterate over the process list, check the name, and call `.kill` on the one you want.

The alternative to finding a crate is writing your own implementations for each system you intend on targeting.

Comment: It's not "bloat" to depend on crates that accomplish the outcome you're looking for (like using system APIs to terminate a process).

Comment: I was referring to all the other features outside of killing a process by name.

Comment: Shouldn't unreachable code (like unused library functions) get optimized out and avoid increasing the size of the resulting binary?

Comment: For the most part, yea.  LTO isn't magic though.  A quick hello world, one with enough code to kill a proc named `yeet` and one without netted a 60%/300kB increase.

Also, you have to compile 14K SLoC but, neither are show stoppers in the right context.

info: https://gist.github.com/mcountryman/f54bf81f141493e204477fd68570ab69

Comment: Honestly, I'm disappointed to hear that link-time optimization is as good as Rust is getting on this count. Twenty-mumble years ago I worked on toolchains that could effectively make everything `static` and inlineable in _C_ and use that for much finer-grained reachability analysis than just "take or leave this whole symbol?". Granted, this was in embedded systems, where compiler time was cheap but target storage and cycles were expensive.